# Should circuit breaker be installed before hand switch?

Tags: switches, safety

I am a student of mechanical engineering so I am not very familiar with electronics. Recently I started working on a project where I am researching a control system for a motor which does some work. The system is powered by 3 phase AC electricity + ground + neutral which comes from 5 pin socket. The 3 phases then are directly connected to a hand switch (ON/OFF) and then to a circuit breaker. My question is as follows: as a standard or following safety requirements, would it be better, if phases are first connected to a circuit breaker and then to a hand switch?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that the power comes from a 5 pin socket. If we assume that you mean a wall outlet, then ostensibly there is already a circuit breaker protecting this circuit. If so, then where you place the selector switch is immaterial now, as the circuit would ALREADY be protected upstream. So you could consider the "hand switch" as an isolator, then the circuit breaker as the motor protection device. Perfectly legitimate if all of those things are true, AND assuming all devices are properly selected and rated for the intended use.

Comment: That exactly reflects the problem I was describing. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Breaker should come first.. I pity the poor person that has to fix the hand-switch.

Comment: The person who fixes it / gets hurt is not the person who installed it incorrectly in most cases , but it should be...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Trevor's post. It is typical to use a three phase contactor that protects against loss of a phase. I've seen motors without this trashed.
[Three Phase Relay](https://www.macromatic.com/blog/relays/what-is-a-phase-loss)

Comment: Right, it is already used, now I know the reason. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Chicken and egg problem. I'd say switch, breaker, switch... just like in house wiring: main switch, circuit breakers, individual switches. However, your 5 pin socket might already have a switch, so the first switch can be left out.

Comment: that's a switch ;)